# finding the max sum of pair-wise products

Tags: java

I am solving a problem in java in which i have to find the maximum pair-wise product of the 2 integer arrays.

**Example:**

```
array 1 -> [1, 3, -5]
array 2 -> [-2, 4, 1]

output: 23            // (3 * 4) + (1 * 1) + (-5 * -2)
```

My currrent code also produces this output.

**My Solution**

sort both arrays and then multiply numbers at same indexes from both arrays and sum the product of each pair.

**Problem**

My solution is tested using test cases that i don't know about. My solution is not able to pass all the test cases. I am not sure if there's any input against which my solution will fail.

**Question**

Is there something wrong with my solution of the given problem which prevents my code from passing all the test cases?

**Code**

```
private static long maxSum(int[] a, int[] b) {
    long result = 0;

    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(b);

    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += a[i] * b[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Problem Description**

[image]

Comment: Can you link the problem?

Comment: Can you try adding a condition as follows:
`if (a == null || b == null) return 0;`
And tell us if the result has changed?
Maybe that's some corner case that makes your code run into a NullPointerException?

Comment: Hmm, seems good, could it be an overflow issue? You may want to try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: @YaronGrushka the description says `1 <= n <= 10^3` so I dont think thats it

Comment: @MitchelPaulin true, but worth a shot. Places like LeetCode love those kinds of corner cases. His approach does look like it should work.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to link us to this judge? Somethings missing here.

Comment: Try like `result += long(a[i]) * long(b[i]);`

Comment: Yeah, I tried myself and the max value you can get from this is `10000000000000` well below the constraints of long.

Comment: This simple code looks good to me. However, when the number of negative numbers within *a* is not equal to the number if negative numbers within *b*, then simply sorting both arrays in descending order *may* not be sufficient.

Comment: @Eklavya although your syntax was not correct but your solution was correct. I had to convert result of multiplication in to `long`. Thank you very much

Comment: Yep, may this will be okay `result += (long)a[i] * (long)b[i];` sometimes language swiching fact

Comment: Forget what I just said. I cannot come up with an example, and I think such example does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is, without access to the judge I can't be sure. Consider the case where `a[i] = 10^5` and `b[i] = 10^5`, the max allowed in the problem, now `a[i] * b[i] = 10^10`. Since `a` and `b` are type integer the intermediary result is stored as an integer. You will get an overflow since the number 10^10 is above the limit of an int.

To fix this you can cast the array value to long.

`result += Long.valueOf(a[i]) * Long.valueOf(b[i]);`